# Convert EXI binary data to XML/JSON and viceversa

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, xsd, exi

TL;DR

What is the best way to use exificient-grammar to generate a GRS file from a XSD, that can be used with exificient-for-javascript?

--

I am developing a TCP server with Nodejs. The clients send data in EXI format. I have the XSD schemas and I would like to convert those bytes, in EXI format, to JSON or similar.

To work with [exificient-for-javascript](https://github.com/EXIficient/exificient-for-json) I need to generate the GRS file with the [exificient-grammars](https://github.com/EXIficient/exificient-grammars) library. I have never worked with Java, but I understand that this library does not have a CLI executable, but you can import it in your project and use it. I have tried to create a java project and using maven I am loading the libraries. I manage to run the project but my little knowledge of Java is making me lose a lot of time with this. In short I am not able to generate the GRS file. My java code (see comment "and now, how to..."):

```
public class Parser {
    Grammars grammar;

    public void parse() {
        System.out.println("Hello from parser");
        try {
            grammar = GrammarFactory.newInstance().createGrammars("VALID_ABSOLUTE_SYSTEM_PATH_TO_XSD");
            // and now, how to generate an output GRS file???
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

On the other hand, the [exificient](https://github.com/EXIficient/exificient) project does provide an executable to convert EXI to XML and vice versa, however in my Nodejs application I get a buffer (an array of int8). It occurs to me that I could generate a binary file from Nodejs and process it with the exificient executable in the background (exec/spawn), but this seems a bit overkill to me.

Answer (score 0):

The class `Grammars2JSON` is what you are looking for.

This class can be called from the command line by passing the XSD as input. It creates the according JSON grammars file.

see https://github.com/EXIficient/exificient-grammars/blob/master/src/main/java/com/siemens/ct/exi/grammars/persistency/Grammars2JSON.java#L658